Openedge - generated code logical variables casing
In the Progress Developer Studio, Appbuilder (eclipse), what config controls the casing of the code generated for logical gui components?
e.g.
CREATE WINDOW...
MAX-BUTTON = no

vs.
CREATE WINDOW...
MAX-BUTTON = NO

My Preference>progress Openedge>editor
has case UPPER, Apply keywords casing on save, as you type case keywords
yet these auto generated insist on being lower case.

Unfortunately there is no such config. The Appbuilder is considered mature by Progress so no further enhancements are done.
See community-archive.progress.com/forums/00019/26774.html
